# Why this Javascript promise does not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am Learning about promises.

```
app.get('/message',function(req, res){    
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("hi");
    });
    promise.then(function(message){
       res.json(message);
    })

});
```

This works good.
Though This is too simple. To write something 'lengthy' I moved the code out of `app.get()` and tried to return the message from the external function... like this:

```
    app.get('/message',function(req, res){ 
      var message = message(); // I also tried wrapping this in promise and calling `res.json` in `promise.then()` but no luck
       res.json(message);
    });

    function message(){    
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve("hi");
        });
        promise.then(function(message){
           return message;
        })

    }
```

So why doesn't the return statement in the `message()` function return the message ? and what's the best practice to move such `promising` code out of my route functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you have a local variable named `message` which masks the module level variable which has the same name and references a function. You need to rename one of them.

Then: You don't have a return statement for the `message` function, so it returns `undefined`.

If you want to get the result of the promise back in the callback function you pass to `get` then you need to:

1. Return the promise
2. Call `then` on it
3. Use `res.json(...);` inside the function you pass to `then`

For example:

```
app.get('/message',function(req, res){ 
  var my_message = message(); 
  my_message.then(function (data) {
     res.json(data);
 });
});

function message(){    
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("hi");
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `message` function doesn't return anything.

You could do:

```
app.get('/message',function(req, res){
    message().then(function (message) {
        res.json(message);
    }
});

function message() {    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("hi");
    });
}
```

Also, be careful to not use the same names for multiple variables, since it makes the code error-prone due to less readabililty.

Comment: Quicker than me :)
If he wants to learn promises, it could be helpful to explain the chainen aspect like in my answer (return promise.then(function(msg) { return msg} )

Answer (score 1):

You can return promise from your message function and use async/await on it like:

```
app.get('/message', async function(req, res){
    var msg = await message();
    res.json(msg);
});
function message() {    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("hi");
    });
}
```

Like:

```js
function message() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1500, 'hi');
  });
}

async function go() {
  console.log('Async call started...');
  var msg = await message();
  console.log(msg);
}

go();
```

Answer (score 0):

The function message does not return the created promise.
Normally you'd have an error saying: cannot read property .then of undefined

```
function message(){    
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("hi");
    });
    return promise.then(function(message){  // This will return the initial promise. Due to to the .then, that promise is chained into resolving into the message
       return message;
    })

}
```

It could be shorted though (in case you do not want the .then in your message function.
Just return the promise then:

```
function message(){    
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve("hi");
});
```

}